# How to find matching BEGIN END pairs in complex SQL Server query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm reverse engineering a gigantic stored procedure. There are tons of BEGIN ENDs in it, not all indented properly, many levels deep, and I am having a heck of a time finding which BEGIN END pairs match each other.

Is there an easy way to find out which pairs match each other. I know in Visual studio you can jump from opening bracket to closing bracket with ctr+] and same thing in SSMS 2008. But I'm using 2005.

Any ideas?

Comment: I can recommend you to format the SQL code with a tool, like: http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Comment: @Lamak: Thanks but that didn't really solve my problem. Neat tool though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005, ctrl+] still works for `}`, it just doesn't work for `BEGIN END`. SQL Server 2005 doesn't distinguish between commented out brackets and uncommented brackets, so my solution was to replace all `BEGIN`s with `BEGIN/*{*/` and all `END`s with `END/*}*/`.

So I had something like this:

```
BEGIN/*{*/

    BEGIN/*{*/

    END/*}*/

END/*}*/
```

With that I was able to jump back and forth to the paired `BEGIN` and `END`.

Look out for `BEGIN TRANSACTION` commands though, you don't want them included in the replace.

Comment: Great idea. Also, make sure you check if the end is not part os a "CASE WHEN". If you are using Azure Data Studio or similar, the shortcut to navigate brackets is Ctrl + Shift + \

Answer (score 3):

I would use a good text editor (like Vim) to replace each BEGIN with `{` and END with `}`, like so:

```
:%s/\<BEGIN\>/{/g
:%s/\<END\>/}/g
```

Note, the `\<` and `\>` are regex metacharacters to ensure you don't match anything other than complete words.

Then in normal mode, place the cursor over the brace character of interest, and hit the `%` key. Vim will take you to the matching brace.

When you are done reformatting to your satisfaction, replace the brace characters with their original keywords.