# How to find matching begin and end statements in SQL Server management Studio 2012?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

How to find matching begin and end statements in SQL Server Management Studio 2012? I have a very long stored proc  with several levels of multi page nested if statements. The SQL is already formatted. My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085741/how-to-find-matching-begin-end-pairs-in-complex-sql-server-query) but I am using SSMS 2012 which now uses Visual Studio Shell. I was wondering if MS added this functionality or if there's an external tool or SSMS plugin that does it.

Otherwise I will have to resort to the solutions in the old question.

Answer (score 36):

If anyone is still looking for an answer to this, it's *CTRL+]*.

Comment: Nice. I didn't know that. Has that always been there?

Comment: I think it's been around for a while, just hidden.

Comment: Very helpful thanks!  Now I'm trying to get SQL to actually _highlight_ the matching syntax pair - whether begin/end or { } or [ ].  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just a caveat - SqlCmd mode on in SSMS disables that.

Comment: SqlCmd mode disabling it is very annoying.

Answer (score 12):

I seem to be able to get code collapsing for BEGIN / END no problem. Observe my settings under Tools > Options  > Text Editor > Transact-SQL:

[image]

And note that I have IntelliSense enabled, with "outline statements" checked, under Tools > Options > Text Editor > Transact-SQL > IntelliSense:

[image]

The line numbers really help. If I collapse a line that contains a BEGIN, the next line number is the one *after* the END:

[image]

Comment: it turns out that if query window is opened in SqlCmd mode, it doesn't work. Super annoying because it's on by default for me because I run quite a few SqlCmd scripts.

Answer (score 6):

This is not an answer, I don't have enough reputation to comment yet.

Other than the solutions pointed in the other topic you mentioned I don't think there is a way. What I do is, delete the `END`, write the `END` again, it will grey out and the `BEGIN`  that matches this `END`will grey out as well. Then I just search through the code for grey words.

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> for jumping from `BEGIN` to matching `END`. Same key for jumping to matching `BEGIN` from the `END`.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to select the block of code as you jump between the `BEGIN` and `END`.

If you have installed SQL Prompt, clicking on `BEGIN` (`END`), highlights the matching `END` (`BEGIN`) in gray.

Answer (score 3):

Function that you need is called Edit.GotoBrace and is present in SSMS v 2008 as well as 2012.
It has different shortcuts, depending on language version of your ssms. I have SSMS2008 EN and SSMS2012 German, my keyboard layout is german. So Shortcuts are:

**SSMS 2008 EN**

Just find matching begin/end

`Edit.GotoBrace Text Editor::Ctrl+´`

the same, but also extend selection

`Edit.GotoBraceExtend Text Editor::Ctrl+Shift+´`

**SSMS 2012 German**

`Edit.GotoBrace (Bearbeiten.GehezuKlammer) Text-Editor::Ctrl+´`

`Edit.GotoBrace (Bearbeiten.GehezuKlammer) Text-Editor::Ctrl+9`

`Edit.GotoBraceExtend (Bearbeiten.ErweiternbisKlammer) Text-Editor::Ctrl+Shift+´`

`Edit.GotoBraceExtend (Bearbeiten.ErweiternbisKlammer) Text-Editor::Ctrl+Shift+9`

In SSMS 2012 you can use native keyboard shortcut manager to view/change the shortcut for this or any other command.
But: Native command has one disadvantage: you have to be on begin/end to jump to paired token.

I develop a free add-in for ssms and have implemented yesterday improved function, that allows to jump to parent begin/end tag from any position in nested code. It will be available in next release. So if you like my idea - wait till next release. Add-in is called SSMSBoost. I have also used it to find quickly answer to your question: - it has "Dump SSMS Shortcuts" & "Dump SSMS commands" functions, which makes a full list of all available functions in ssms (and it allows to re-define shortcuts in SSMS2008, where shortcuts manager is abscent)

Comment: Update: as promised, we have implemented "go to BEGIN/END" in SSMSBoost add-in. Now Ctrl+Shift-UpArrow will navigate to BEGIN and Ctrl+Shift-DownArrow will navigate to END